how to add system environment variable __SDKDIR__ with path where all the dependencies lives
we're tryin to copile on windows 11 a open source Grand Theft Auto 1 remake project.
and it says that on windows u must add system environment variable SDKDIR with path where all the dependencies lives. These dependencies are:
GLEW
GLM
OpenAL-Soft
this is our 2nd time in visual studio 2017 and we'r lookin for resources
we'r lookin for people who hav built the project before or people with general visual studio copiling experience
